# F#: What is the difference between [0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5] and [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]?

Tags: list, f#

I know how to make a list:

```
let f n = 
    let out_listA = [ 0 .. (n - 1) ]
    let out_list =
        out_listA |> List.reduce (fun state item -> state + ", " + item) 
    out_list
```

I am working with on-line exercises that involving printing something that looks like the following if `n = 5`.

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

instead of

```
[0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
```

From looking on the web, the comma-separated output appears to be a list converted to a string.

So, my question is what does `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` represent, and what is actually taking place, when converting from the list separated by semicolons to separated by commas?

***Epilogue:***

Fyodor Soikin's comment was correct; I was confused.

It turns out, the comma-separated list was a contrivance to print out a semicolon-separated list as a comma-separated list inside array brackets.

The following solution came from [ehotinger](https://github.com/ehotinger/HackerRank) on github:

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]

let main argv = 
    let s = Console.ReadLine() |> int
    seq { for i in 1..s do yield i }
    |> Seq.fold (fun s i ->
        if s = "" then sprintf "%i" i
        else sprintf "%s, %i" s i) ""
    |> (fun s -> sprintf "[%s]" s)
    |> Console.WriteLine

0 // return an integer exit code
```

I thought the list had been converted. Well it had been converted into a string containing square brackets and a comma-separated list of numbers inside the brackets.

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question ? *So, my question is what does [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] represent* **From looking on the web, the comma-separated output appears to be a list converted to a string.**

Comment: @Sehnsucht Except that it's not converting the list to a string. I was going to explain but Rob beat me so see his answer below.

Comment: @Kittoes0124 see my comment to his answer

Comment: @Sehnsucht I misunderstood what the problem set was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In F#, a comma is a delimiter for a tuple.

So when you see something like this:

```
match x, y with
| 1.1, 2.2 -> doSomething()
| 2.2, 3.3 -> doSomethingElse()
| _ -> defaultAction()
```

that is shorthand for

```
match (x, y) with
| (1.1, 2.2) -> doSomething()
| (2.2, 3.3) -> doSomethingElse()
| _ -> defaultAction()
```

So in fact your array `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` contains only one element: the tuple `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`. To verify this, try doing this quick test in your REPL:

```
let test = ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] = [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)])
```

**ADDENDUM**

In fact, the F# Interactive window is a very good tool for answering similar questions. As well as the test above, you can also simply highlight the following lines and hit Ctrl+Enter:

```
let value1 = [0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
let value2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The output is

```
val value1 : int list = [0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
val value2 : (int * int * int * int * int * int) list = [(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
```

which answers the question very succinctly. True to the nature of F#, it reproduces my long-winded answer in two lines.

Comment: except there is no tuple involved here, that can't be, it would require to somehow fold a list into tuple of increasing length which isn't possible as the folder function has to return the same type each time

Comment: Just evaluate [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].[0] in F# interactive.

Comment: @Sehnsucht, Rob correctly answered the OP's question "_So, my question is what does [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] represent_". The OP is a bit confused, yes, but I think this is a good enough answer at least to start.

Comment: The result is val it : int * int * int * int * int * int = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Comment: I'm not saying that we can't make a function of one item which is a 6 length tuple ; but we can't construct that from a list of 6 items by folding. Neither did I say the answer was incorrect, it describes what is a list of one tuple. I'm just pointing out that in the given context there is little related to tuple in the problem as described (especially the second part of the OP question)

Comment: So, are you saying convert the list to a tuple?

Comment: The first part of the question is not really related to the last part. In the first part, the OP has generated a string containing an output; in the second part, they ask what that output represents. In the REPL, a comma-separated list of characters in square brackets represents an array with a single entry.

Comment: That's partly what I was trying to point out ; the question is 2 fold (pun intended) and I focused on the last part ; probably not being fluent made the wording of all that harsh

Comment: OP -- I'm not saying that. Your code seems to work. It generates a specific output, which will be interpreted as an array containing a single tuple if you pasted it into F# interactive.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I've added an addendum to the OP. You're right I was confused.